# Regex capture group nesting

Tags: regex

I've just started learning regex and I've been stuck on [this lesson](http://regexone.com/lesson/12) for a while now.

[image]

I don't quite understand why the below 2 won't work.

```
^(.+(\d+))$

^([a-zA-Z_]+(\d+))$
```

Comment: How don't they work? What are you trying to do with them?

Comment: You need to show the strings you're trying to match with them, and what you expect each capture group to contain.

Comment: Sorry I posted the link to it but should have put it in the question. It's solved now anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @user3204597 Please update the question for the benefit of all the future readers. SO isn't just for your personal benefit, we're trying to build a permanent, useful knowledge base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both work ok, but you need a space before the nested group.

Your regex would work if the text was for example: `Jan1987`. But the examples in the link you posted are like: `Jan 1987`

Try:

```
^(.+ (\d+))$

^([a-zA-Z_]+ (\d+))$
```

Answer (score 1):

For this `^(.+(\d+))$`
If we put a capture group around `(.+)`
From the output we see that for `.+`, the engine initially matches
the entire string `Jan 1987` then backtracks 1 character at a time until
it can satisfy the next sub-expression `(\d+)`.
It finds character `7` and sees that satisfies the expression.
Its done its job, all sub-expression's are satisfied, so it stops.

That's typical behavior of *greedy* quantifiers. 
Some things that could disrupt this behavior:

1. Add a non-greedy qualifier  `?` to the expression:
   Looks like this `(.+?)`. What this does is instead of initially matching
   the entire string, it incrementally matches 1 character at a time.
   Each time it matches a character it checks the next character to see if it
   would match the *next* sub-expression `\d+`. Since it does, it leaves the current sub-expression `.+?` and continues with the next one `\d+`.
   The process continues onto the next sub-expression, etc..
   Any time it fails along the way, the engine goes back to the previous  successful sub-expression, at its previous successful match position,
   then *decrements* that match position, then repeats the whole process.
   It could go all the way back to the very first sub-expression with this
   process... This is called *backtracking*.
2. Keep the greedy sub-expression `.+` but at certain points add
   known literal  character(s) just before the next sub-expression.
   These are waypoints for the engine to anchor on and are called pseudo-anchors.
   It disrupts backtracking. For example, you could have added a space literal
   just before the `\d+`  sub-expression, like `^(.+ (\d+))$`. This forces the
   engine to *backtrack* from the last digit, back until it finds a space,   letting  `\d+` consume all the year digits.
3. Stay greedy, but reduce the allowed characters in sub-expressions.
   Instead of using the *Dot* meta-character (matches any character), specify
   a class of limited characters.

In general, use the *Dot* meta-character where either you don't care what is
there, or don't know what's there. It will always be faster than classes.
However, when using this, try to have a strategy of pseudo-anchors in the
following sub-expression. This will allow the engine to zero in, where it
matches at the right *frame* point for your subject text.

```
 ^ 
 (                             # (1 start)
      ( .+ )                        # (2)
      ( \d+ )                       # (3)
 )                             # (1 end)
 $
```

Output:

```
  **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 8 ) 
 Jan 1987  
  **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 8 ) 
 Jan 1987  
  **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 0 , len 7 ) 
 Jan 198  
  **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 7 , len 1 ) 
 7
```